# PHP strtotime() with date() issue with year field

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a problem when i am converting a String Date datatype into a date time format.
I am using this code

```
$birthday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rec['birthday']));
```

The problem is that when only 'Date-Month' fields are coming then it will generate by default '1970'.But i want to save this as 'Date-Month-0000'.how can we solve this problelm.

Comment: what value does `$rec['birthday']` have ?

Comment: MM/DD,sometime and some fields MM/DD/YYYY ,actually these  data are coming from others site.

Comment: so you want to convert `MM/DD` to `Y-m-d` format ?

Comment: yes,it is working when all fields are set ,but creating a problem when "YYYY" is not set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
$rec['birthday']= "03/11/2011";
if(isset($rec['birthday']) && $rec['birthday'] != "")
{
    $dates = explode("/",$rec['birthday']);
  if(!isset($dates[2]))
     $dates[2] = "0000";
    $newdate = $dates[0]."-".$dates[1]."-".$dates[2];
echo $newdate;
}
else
{
    $newdate="";
}
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/2EkZ5)

**NOTE:** `$rec['birthday']` should be in format `DD/MM` or `DD/MM/YY`

Comment: but without adding condions when i am passing a year value to it,it is also generating 03-11-0000

Comment: so you want to replace 0000 by year if year is there in date ?

Comment: @user3351494 if this not the one you are looking then, please explain more clearly, probably with sample input and sample output

Comment: ok...wait i am doing this and it is not taking still 0000.it replacing year field with current year i.e. 2014

Comment: @user3351494 even if year is there you want only 0000 as year ?

Comment: i mean to say if a user do not have a birthdate then it is showing --0000

Comment: $dates = explode("/",$rec['birthday']);
   if(!isset($dates[2]))
   {
    $dates[2] = "0000";
    $birthday = $dates[0]."-".$dates[1]."-".$dates[2];
    }else{
    $birthday = $dates[0]."-".$dates[1]."-".$dates[2];
    }

Comment: if user does not have birthday you dont want to do any thing ?

Comment: it is still taking curret year by default dude i.e. 2014

Comment: i think you are making some mistake while applying. because in demo it works fine. so cloud you share us how you implement the solution ?

Comment: well there is according to your code if year is not coming then it is taking into the database all fields as 0000-00-00

Answer (score 0):

try This:
*Date Format(dd/mm/yyyy)*

```
$date = explode('/', $rec['birthday']);
if(sizeof($date) == 2)
{
  $new_date = $date[0].'/'.$date[1].'/'.'0000';
}

else
{
   $new_date = $rec['birthday'];
}
```

Comment: '1970' is not coming bydefault dude.if it is blank then it should be '0000'.

Comment: @user3351494 you can ignore if condition

Comment: the output format differs from the one OP asks which is `DD-MM-YY`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$date = explode('/', $rec['birthday']);

if(!isset($date[2])){
  $new_date = $date[0].'-'.$date[1].'-'.'0000';
}
else{
  $new_date = $date[0].'-'.$date[1].'-'.$date[2];
}
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/obLjS)